# Apache: how to protect mod_info output

Tags: apache, security

I use [Apache's `mod_info`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_info.html) to display detailed information about my server setup.

**httpd-vhosts.conf**

```
# Set path below to be handled by mod_info. It will show server info. 
# For this to work, this module must be loaded (uncommented in httpd.conf)
<Location /special/path>
   SetHandler server-info
   Order allow,deny
   Allow from 127.0.0.1
</Location>
```

`Allow from` is set to the local machine because this is on my dev machine.

This module allows me to see a tremendous amount of information by navigating to `/special/path`.  I'd like to get the same benefit on my production server, so I can see the output remotely. This means I need to make the path publicly accessible but of course keep that info away from prying eyes.

What's the most practical way to protect that output? I'm ok with a static password challenge so long as the password is not stored in the clear (hashed is ok) and definitely not stored in a publicly accessible location.

`Apache 2.4.16`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To solve my problem, I used this configuration:

```
# All paths beginning with /admin will be password protected with
# credentials from /path/admin.htpasswd
<Location /admin>
  AuthType Basic
  AuthName "Administrators"
  AuthBasicProvider file
  AuthUserFile "/path/admin.htpasswd"
  Require valid-user
</Location>

<IfModule info_module>
    <Location /admin/server-info>
        SetHandler server-info
    </Location>
</IfModule>
```

The `.htpasswd` file contains one `{username}:{hashed password}` per line. Eg:

```
linda:$apr1$hq20V6OX$uKFyONT91I1BhCae0YJ7B1
eric:$apr1$h4XrUUNS$Hi61JTs1nQOgI/ehMnC0X0
```

I used the password hash generator from [htaccesstools.com](http://www.htaccesstools.com/htpasswd-generator/)